# how to design a qualified uml class diagram?

Tags: uml

A question from java interview:
You have to design a system that will manage 3 ducks:
The first one knows how to swim and fly, the second knows to swim and to hunt, the third knows to swim, fly and hunt. Describe the UML class diagram and explain the terms abstract class and interface. End of question.
In my opinion, i would create a "Duck" class with a method swim() in it, and 2 more classes "flyingDuck" and "huntingDuck" will derive from "Duck", and will contain the methods fly() and hunt() respectivly. One more class will be "universalDuck" and it will derive from "huntingDuck" and will contain the method eat(). What do you think ? Is this a good design or it's better to do it with interfaces ?

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/108240/why-are-interfaces-useful

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to model a "universalDuck" extending "huntingDuck" by the method eat()? Was this asked for in your Java interview question?

Since the question asked for explanations of the terms abstract class and interface, you are probably expected to use these concepts in your model. For having a duck3 as an instance of a class that inherits both fly() from "flyingDuck" and hunt() from "huntingDuck" you will need to use interfaces for "flyingDuck" and "huntingDuck" because in Java you can only have multiple inheritance from interfaces.